# Convert DateTime String with TimeZone to the DateTime with TimeZone Or in UTC in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

I received DateTime String from Fedex in following format

```
"2012-06-22T21:39:48-05:00"
```

I want to convert this string into the TimeZone for ex:-

```
Fri, 23 Jun 2012 02:39:48 +0000
```

Is there any method which converts this string into the utc time directly?

I want something similar to following

```
date_and_time = '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
DateTime.strptime("2012-06-22T21:39:48 Central Time (US & Canada)", date_and_time)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
DateTime.parse("2012-06-22T21:39:48-05:00").utc
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go :

```
"2012-06-22T21:39:48-05:00".to_time.utc.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
```